# How to split with multiple delimiters

Tags: java

I have a string variable like this
this is#3 a test, line#1 one

I want to split it into string array like this

this is a test line one

I am using this code:

```
String test = "This is#3 a test, line#1 one";
String[] test2 = test.split("(,#)");
```

But I want to know that how I can remove digits after # sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split argument is just regular expression. So use `\d` and `\s` capture groups:

```
String[] test2 = test.split("[,#\\s\\d]+");
```

Also notice, I added `+` after `[...]` - this will allow consider as delimiter sequence of characters, not only single chars.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in two steps :

1)  Replace the `#` + following digits with `,` .

2)  Split on `,`

```
String[] test2 = test.replaceAll("#[0-9]*", ",").split(",");
```